# How to change my code to solve modular equations with division?

Tags: python, math, modulo, modular-arithmetic

I wrote the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, but i'm having trouble with using it to solve the following equation:

[image: (743360//1008//x)=272 (mod 1009)]

which the [Modular Equation Solver](https://www.dcode.fr/modular-equation-solver) reduces to

[image: 743360/1008x = 272 (mod 1009)]

and

[image: x == 116]

Here is my code:

```py
def fastlinearcongruenceSO(powx, divmodx, N, withstats=False): 
 x, y, z = egcditerx2SO(powx, N, withstats) 
 answer = (y*divmodx)%N 
 if withstats == True: 
    print(f"answer = {answer}") 
 if x > 1: 
    powx//=x 
    divmodx//=x 
    N//=x 
    if withstats == True: 
      print(f"powx = {powx}, divmodx = {divmodx}, N = {N}") 
    x, y, z = egcditerx2SO(powx, N, withstats) 
    if withstats == True: 
      print(f"x = {x}, y = {y}, z = {z}") 
    answer = (y*divmodx)%N 
    if withstats == True: 
       print(f"answer = {answer}") 
 return answer

def egcditerx2SO(a, b, withstats=False): 
  s = 0 
  r = b 
  old_s = 1 
  old_r = a 
  quotient = 0
  if withstats == True: 
      print(f"quotient = {quotient}, old_r = {old_r}, r = {r}, old_s = {old_s}, s = {s}") 
  while r!= 0: 
    quotient = old_r // r 
    old_r, r = r, old_r - quotient * r 
    old_s, s = s, old_s - quotient * s 
    if withstats == True: 
      print(f"quotient = {quotient}, old_r = {old_r}, r = {r}, old_s = {old_s}, s = {s}") 
  if b != 0: 
    bezout_t = quotient = (old_r - old_s * a) // b 
    if withstats == True: 
      print(f"bezout_t = {bezout_t}") 
  else: 
    bezout_t = 0 
  if withstats == True: 
    print("Bézout coefficients:", (old_s, bezout_t)) 
    print("greatest common divisor:", old_r) 
  return old_r, old_s, bezout_t
```

To solve for inverses, i used this form:

```
IN: fastlinearcongruenceSO(327, 1, 1009)
OUT: 108
```

I'm not sure how or what changes i need to make to modify it to solve with the form of division, does anyone have any ideas of what changes i need to make or if i can solve it using my existing code?  I really want to modify my code to handle it solving this equation:  `743360/1008x = 272 (mod 1009)` and `x == 116` or for someone to let me know how that equation was solved, and i can then with those steps modify my code to solve for division based modulus equations. Thanks for anyone who knows how to solve these division based equations.

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation with two slashes. What is the binary operation that is denoted with two slashes.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk it;s a div.  https://www.dcode.fr/modular-equation-solver  reduces (7433660//1008//x)=272 (mod 1009)  to 743360/1008x = 272 (mod 1009).  I absolutely can't seem to use EGCD to solve this so hoping for some help. dcode.fr solves it as x=116

Comment: The standard notation for division is a single slash. In python, there is a double slash operator that performs floored division. Your question is labelled python but the equation looks like a mixture of standard math notation with some python notation thrown in. Therefore I cannot figure out what the equation truly means.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk  I added a picture at the bottom that might help

Comment: I can solve many linear congruences using egcd and egcd division, but this form with the division on the left i can't seem to figure out how to solve and want to write a program that will do so as dcode.fr can. I'm subscribed to wolfram alpha, but couldn't figure out how to input the equation to see if i could get a step by step solution

Comment: No, it doesn't help, because it doesn't explain why you used two slashes instead of one. The modular solver is just multiplying both side by x/272 to get the solution x=116.

Comment: I sortof solved it by doing this: 1009 - fastlinearcongruencex2(744360//1009,1, 1009) + 1 = 116